# Can you instanciate a class inside its own entry point?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
class Program 
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run(args);
    }

    void Run(string[] args)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Now this works as I expect it to, and certainly I can't see anything obviously wrong, but instinctually this code worries me.  So I have three questions:

- Is this behavior well defined by the compiler?
- Is this code doing what I expect it to?
- Is this code in keeping with best practices?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with what you are doing.  Static methods create instances of the surrounding class all the time (see the singleton pattern, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is valid code and does what you expect it to do.

Main is just a static method. The fact that it is the entry point, just means that the CLR calls it at startup. It is perfectly valid to instantiate a class in a static method, and call methods on it.

Comment: Yep, its just another method. Its only special because it is called once at startup. There is no harm in calling the method again at a later point it doesn't do anything different to other static methods so don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes, and yes. I don't see why it should trouble anyone.

An entry point like `Main()` is not the same as a constructor, plus it's static. When it runs, the class is fully defined, all static members are available, and instances can be created without any problems.